# Firebase returns false value when there is a value present in the collection using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to verify a record in Firebase before registering the user with post request using node.js

***** Node.js Code ****

```
function checkUserExist(email) {
    var userExist = false;
    userRef.orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            userExist = true;
            console.log(userExist); // Here the value is returned true
        }
    });
    return userExist;
}

app.post('/register', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {

    var testUser = checkUserExist(req.body.reg_email);
    console.log('A: '+ testUser);
    // Here the value is returned false instead of true

    console.log(checkUserExist(req.body.reg_email), req.body.reg_email);
    // Here the value is returned false instead of true
    var newUserObj = {
        first_name: req.body.reg_first_name,
        last_name: req.body.reg_last_name,
        email: req.body.reg_email
    };

    userRef.push(newUserObj);

    res.render('pages/register', { reg_data: { post_data: req.body, is_success: created, is_user_exist: checkUserExist(req.body.reg_email) } });
    //console.log(users);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. By the time your `return userExist` runs, the data hasn't loaded yet.

This is easiest to see with some logging statements:

```
console.log('Before starting query');
userRef.orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
  console.log('Got query results');
});
console.log('After starting query');
```

When you run this code, you get this output:

> Before starting query
>
> After starting query
>
> Got query results

That is probably not the order you expected, but it explains precisely why your method returns the wrong value: the data hasn't been loaded yet by the time your function returns.

Any code that needs the data from the database, must either be inside the `then()` callback, or be called from there.

The common way to deal with asynchronous APIs is to return a promise:

```
function checkUserExist(email) {
    var userExist = false;
    return userRef.orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        return snapshot.exists();
    });
}
```

Now you can call `checkUserExist` like this:

```
checkUserExist(req.body.reg_email).then(function(userExists) {;
  console.log(userExists);
})
```

Note that here too, the `userExists` only has the correct value *inside* the `then()` callback.

---

If you're on a modern JavaScript environment, you can use `async`/`await` for the function call:

```
let userExists = await checkUserExist(req.body.reg_email);
console.log(userExists);
```

Note that this is still doing the asynchronous call behind the scenes.

This is a very common problem for developers new to dealing with asynchronous APIs. I highly recommend you check out some of these previous answers:

- [Reading nested data from Firebase returns something else than an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55670143/reading-nested-data-from-firebase-returns-something-else-than-an-array/55670891#55670891)
- [Best way to retrieve Firebase data and return it, or an alternative way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905600/best-way-to-retrieve-firebase-data-and-return-it-or-an-alternative-way/34908497#34908497)
- [Why Does Firebase Lose Reference outside the once() Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40688268/why-does-firebase-lose-reference-outside-the-once-function/40688890#40688890)
- [Asynchronous access to an array in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049342/asynchronous-access-to-an-array-in-firebase)