# firebase database function return value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, return-value

I am trying to return a value after i read the data from firebase but ai am not getting it right:

This is what i have:

```
bill = database.ref('/restaurant/' + orderTest.restaurantKey ).once('value').then(snapchot =>{
      restaurantData = snapchot.val()
      *some functions that make billTest to 0
      billTest = 0;
      return billTest;
    });
```

What i get from that is this when i console log bill is this:

```
ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}
__zone_symbol__state: true
__zone_symbol__value: 0
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): (...)
__proto__: Object
```

but i want to get just the normal value of 0.

I know that i am doing something wrong, but i tried everything that i know. I am also a begginer so i am here asking for some help

Comment: I will try that in a moment

Comment: When i use that i get this error "Assigned expression type Promise<any> is not assignable to type number"

Comment: None of the code in my answer is assigning a promise to a number as far as I can see. Which line is giving that error?

Comment: Hey @Fábio. Any update?

Answer (score 1):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. The closest you can get to what you have now is by using the `async` / `await` keywords:

```
const snapshot = await database.ref('/restaurant/' + orderTest.restaurantKey ).once('value')

restaurantData = snapchot.val()
billTest = 0;
return billTest;
```

I recommend spending some time reading up on asynchronous methods calls, for example with:

- [Firebase returns false value when there is a value present in the collection using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55792452/firebase-returns-false-value-when-there-is-a-value-present-in-the-collection-usi)
- the MDN guide on [asynchronous web development](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous)
- [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)